# Would a text written by a Rishi classified as Hindu scripture?

Tags: rishi, classification

Would a text written by a *Rishi* classified as *Hindu* scripture? If yes, are there any exceptions where a text written by a Rishi would not be considered as a *Hindu* scripture?

Comment: No, if a Rishi composes a text which is not about Hinduism, that wouldn't be a Hindu scripture. Shwetaketu composed the original Kama Shastra, on which Vatsayana's later work was based.  But that's not considered a scripture.  (Technically Shwetaketu isn't a Rishi, for reasons that I discuss [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10881/36), but the point stands.)

Comment: All scriptures are compiled by Rishis, so technically the answer would be yes. But since obviously you have another hidden reason for this question, why don't you add that as well? Like you can classify what do you mean by exception.

Comment: @Keshav Okay, that is one of the exceptions...

Comment: @Surya It is not really hidden intention as you can figure it out without me mentioning it :P I am just following a logical progression in asking my questions, hence nothing hidden.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: As you mention that Shwetaketu was not a Rishi, hence by your own logic, that is not an exception.

Comment: @AmitSaxena Well, my point was that even if an actual rishi had written the Kama Shastra rather than Shwetaketu, it still wouldn't be a Hindu scripture, because only works composed by rishis which are about Hinduism constitute Hindu scripture.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: I might agree to what you are saying if you could provide an actual example. Otherwise, it stays hypothetical.

Comment: @Surya I thought, the direction in which this is heading, might become unnecessarily controversial. Although, the new information I have received after asking a couple of such questions, it won't.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.Surya is right. E.g., Brahmā Purāṇa is a work of Agastya ṛṣi(Rishi). That said, our ṛṣis are deemed authorities, meaning that if they asserted something (even without proof), it has weight which means their commandments are to be followed at all times.

Keep in mind that there are various hierarchies of ṛṣis and this information helps us to gauge their teachings' genuineness/importance → only ① Mahā & ② Brahma ṛṣis' say hold weight.